# Where do discontinuities in the electromagnetic field occur?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, approximations, models

At a superconductor is what I know of, but what are some other cases?

Comment: Do you mean like textbook discontinuities in EM field?

Comment: A superconductor doesn't cause a discontinuity in an em field.

Answer (score 3):

The Maxwell equations,

\begin{align}
\nabla \cdot \mathbf{E}& = \frac {\rho} {\varepsilon_0}
&
\nabla \cdot \mathbf{B}& = 0
\\
\nabla \times \mathbf{E}& = -\frac{\partial \mathbf{B}} {\partial t}
&
\nabla \times \mathbf{B}& = \mu_0\left(\mathbf{J} + \varepsilon_0 \frac{\partial \mathbf{E}} {\partial t} \right)
\end{align}

define the derivatives of the fields. A discontinuity in a function corresponds to a point where its rate of change is infinite. So you can have field discontinuities where the right-hand sides of Maxwell’s equations are infinite. The classic examples are when the charge density $\rho$ or the current density $\mathbf J$ represent a nonzero charge or current confined to zero volume, such as at a point charge, at a line charge or line current, or at a surface charge or a surface current. Your favorite textbook will discuss the conditions the fields must obey across such a boundary.